# How do I correctly format a list of dictioanries being appended so I can write to a Json file

Tags: python, json, string, web-scraping, format

```py
the_list = {f'Game {count}': [{f"{x['vTeam']['triCode']}": f"{x['vTeam']['score']}"},{f"{x['hTeam']['triCode']}",f"{x['hTeam']['score']}"}], 'Time': f"{game_live}"}
    out_file.append(the_list)
```

- I am unable to write this to a JSON file.
- Count is an integer as are all [score] values. Everything else (`game_live`, `triCode`) are strings. I contiunally get various unable to write this to json file errors and I was wondering if I could get some assistance.
- I believe I've formatted the JSON string incorrectly.

The code is apart of a for loop for a web scraper and it iterates 3-4 times.
Below is the outputted string

```json
[{'Game 1': [{'TOR': '115'}, {'PHI', '109'}], 'Time': '7:00 PM ET'}, {'Game 1': [{'IND': '98'}, {'89', 'UTA'}], 'Time': 'Currently Live'}, {'Game 1': [{'MIA': '30'}, {'LAC', '21'}], 'Time': 'Currently Live'}]
```

- I wish to write the above string to a json file

Comment: You need to include double quotes `"` around key names. -edited to correct wrong assumption

Comment: I think this `{f"{x['hTeam']['triCode']}",f"{x['hTeam']['score']}` is your problem, probably an accident: You create `set`s here - instead of `dict`s, would be my guess. Use `{f"{x['hTeam']['triCode']}": f"{x['hTeam']['score']}` instead.

Comment: Thank you both. Both solutions fixed the problem!